# Generating Custom JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a database query which needs to encoded in json format in PHP,I need the data to be encoded in particular format.

The format I want is

```
{
    "Car tyre Showroom":{"ABCD":"1234567","CDEF":"90000000","PPPP":"1000000"},
    "Bike tyre Showroom":{"AFGH":"32124235","AAAAA":"9111111111"},
    "Car Driving School":{"AMNB ":"45565778"},
    "Car battery shop":{"PLQA":"4235346456"}
}
```

But I am getting in the format of

```
    {
        "Car tyre Showroom":{"PPPP":"1000000"}
    },{
        "Bike tyre Showroom":{"AAAAA":"9111111111"}
    },{
        "Car Driving School":{"AMNB ":"45565778"}
    },{
        "Car battery shop":{"PLQA":"4235346456"}
    }
```

My database query is:

```
 $query = "select S.SpecificCategoryName,A.* from specificcategories S,areaspecificdealers A where A.SpecificCategoryId=S.SpecificCategoryId and A.LocationCode=(Select LocationCode from arealist where LocationName='".$location."')";
```

And I have encoded json this way,

```
 for($col = 0; $col < count($result); $col++)
{




        $values[$result[$col]['SpecificCategoryName']]= array($result[$col]['ClientName']=>$result[$col]['PhoneNumber']);


}
```

echo json_encode($values);

Kindly help how to encode data in the above way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$result=array();    
for($row = 0; $row < count($result); $row++)
    {
           $result[$result[$row]['SpecificCategoryName']]= array($result[$row]['DealerName1']=>$result[$row]['PhoneNumber1']);
    }
echo json_encode($result);
```